# valgrind give error when printing the second line to file

Tags: valgrind, system-calls, writetofile, fortran95

I'm using valgrind to find faults in my code. The command I use is

```
 valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out
```

and I compile the code with `-g` code alone. I get many errors pointing to a single write line (The three printed values are initialized and well defined).

```
write (22,*) avlength, stdlength, avenergy
```

All with the `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` error. The said line is the second line from a bunch of lines printing to a single file. At the end of the errors, I get two more, one pointing to the line opening the file

```
resStep = int(conf*100/iterate)
               if (resStep.lt.10) then
                  write (resFile, "(A5,I1)") "res00",resStep
               elseif (ResStep.lt.100) then
                  write (resFile, "(A4,I2)") "res0",resStep
               else 
                  write (resFile, "(A3,I1)") "res",resStep
               endif
               open (unit=22,file=trim(resFile),status='replace', 
     c                 action='write')
```

`resStep` is integer. The error is `Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)`. Finally, I get an error `Address 0x52d83f4 is 212 bytes inside a block of size 8,344 alloc'd` when I flush the file (before closing it).

I can't find any logic here. If the problem is with opening the file in a faulty way, wouldn't I get the error at the first line?

I use f95 to compile this and my gcc version is 4.1.2. I can't upgrade any of it.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: check the data type of `resFile`. Is it a string or a unit number?

My Fortran 95 is beyond rusty but try moving the call to **open()** before the calls to **write()** and pass an integer **resUnit** instead of **resFile** as the first argument to **write()**:

```
CHARACTER(LEN=20):: resFile
INTEGER(KIND=2)  :: resUnit, resStep

resStep = 1
resFile = 'MY-results'
resUnit = 22
open (unit=resUnit, file=trim(resFile), status='replace', action='write')
write(resUnit, "(A5,I1)") "res00", resStep

END
```

Comment: character (len=20) :: resFile. My fortran Foo is really poor. I'm updating my professor code for my needs.

Comment: @Yotam, try moving open() before write() and passing a unit instead of a character(len=20) to open(). I've updated my answer with a short stand alone program that works.